# Form date from string using mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
[
  {
    _id:1 value: "8 Aug 2022, 1:13 PM"
  },
  {
    _id:2 value: "15 Aug 2022, 1:13 PM"
  }
]
```

Want to convert the above documents with the value field as ISO Date.

Converting the value to ISO Date

```
aggregate(
[{"$set":
   {"months":
     ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
      "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    "parts":{"$split":["$value", " "]}}},
 {"$set":
   {"add12?":{"$eq":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$parts", 4]}, "PM"]},
    "hour":
     {"$toInt":
       {"$first":{"$split":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$parts", 3]}, ":"]}}},
    "minute":
     {"$toInt":
       {"$arrayElemAt":
         [{"$split":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$parts", 3]}, ":"]}, 1]}}}},
 {"$set":
   {"date":
     {"$dateFromParts":
       {"year":
         {"$toInt":
           {"$replaceOne":
             {"input":{"$arrayElemAt":["$parts", 2]},
              "find":",",
              "replacement":""}}},
        "month":
         {"$add":
           [{"$indexOfArray":["$months", {"$arrayElemAt":["$parts", 1]}]},
            1]},
        "day":{"$toInt":{"$arrayElemAt":["$parts", 0]}},
        "hour":{"$cond":["$add12?", {"$add":[12, "$hour"]}, "$hour"]},
        "minute":"$minute"}}}}])
```

When the value field in the documents is not in the correct format,
Eg: Correct format:   value: "8 Aug 2022, 1:13 PM"

Incorrect format: value : "Hello" (Anything that could not be convert to date)

Value field should be set to null

Comment: I would suggest a 3rd party library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/). Most of them provide parsing and validation out of the box. However, you cannot use them directly in aggregation pipeline, you would need to loop over your collection data. My favorite is luxon, because in Day.js I don't like the parsing behavior, see https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/1729 or https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format

Answer (score 0):

You can try, using a regex match to see if a value matches your pattern, if it is convert it into a `date`, otherwise set the `date` and `value` as well.

The regex will be something like this:

`(\\d){1,2}\\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\\s(\\d){4},\\s(\\d){1,2}:(\\d){1,2}\\s(AM|PM)`

And the query will be like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "months": [
        "Jan",
        "Feb",
        "Mar",
        "Apr",
        "May",
        "Jun",
        "Jul",
        "Aug",
        "Sep",
        "Oct",
        "Nov",
        "Dec"
      ],
      "parts": {
        "$split": [
          "$value",
          " "
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "add12?": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$parts",
              4
            ]
          },
          "PM"
        ]
      },
      "hour": {
        "$toInt": {
          "$first": {
            "$split": [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$parts",
                  3
                ]
              },
              ":"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "minute": {
        "$toInt": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            {
              "$split": [
                {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$parts",
                    3
                  ]
                },
                ":"
              ]
            },
            1
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "date": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "$value",
              "regex": "(\\d){1,2}\\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\\s(\\d){4},\\s(\\d){1,2}:(\\d){1,2}\\s(AM|PM)"
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$dateFromParts": {
              "year": {
                "$toInt": {
                  "$replaceOne": {
                    "input": {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$parts",
                        2
                      ]
                    },
                    "find": ",",
                    "replacement": ""
                  }
                }
              },
              "month": {
                "$add": [
                  {
                    "$indexOfArray": [
                      "$months",
                      {
                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                          "$parts",
                          1
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  1
                ]
              },
              "day": {
                "$toInt": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$parts",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              },
              "hour": {
                "$cond": [
                  "$add12?",
                  {
                    "$add": [
                      12,
                      "$hour"
                    ]
                  },
                  "$hour"
                ]
              },
              "minute": "$minute"
            }
          },
          "else": null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "value": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$date",
              null
            ]
          },
          "then": null,
          "else": "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This is the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_PpsmBX3SiH). This solution only checks for the format, it doesn't validate the `value` itself, whether the date is valid or not. If that is what you want to do. I'd suggest doing the conversion at the application level rather than at the database directly.